# Ansible - how to use if condition to set variable in jinja based on inventory_hostname

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I have an ansible jinja which is making use of variable {{ mydata }} the value of this variable differs for each host available in the inventory. I am trying to use if condition in my vars to set it up but it's throwing below error. Can someone guide me?

Jinja :

appkey = {{ mydata }}

vars/vars.yml
{% if inventory_hostname == "my-host-name" %}
mydata: myvalue
{% endif %}

```
Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)\n\nSyntax Error while loading YAML.\n  found character that cannot start any token\n\nThe error appears to be in
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the data into a dictionary

```yaml
    mydata_dict:
      my_host_name: myvalue
      default: default value
    mydata: "{{ mydata_dict[inventory_hostname]|default(mydata_dict.default) }}"
```

For example the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: my_host_name,my_host_name2
  vars:
    mydata_dict:
      my_host_name: myvalue
      default: default value
    mydata: "{{ mydata_dict[inventory_hostname]|default(mydata_dict.default) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: mydata
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [my_host_name] => 
  mydata: myvalue
ok: [my_host_name2] => 
  mydata: default value
```